# Zend_Db_Table_Row_Exception

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework, zend-db-table

I have this query below which I am trying to port to Zend (even further below lol). I am getting this error:

> Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Table_Row_Exception' with message
>   'Specified column "admin_vfname" is not in the row'

But when I echo the $select and copy the sql into Navicat it runs fine? What is wrong with it because I can't clearly identify it?

```
SELECT `pay_administrator_actions`.*, `pay_administrator_actions`.* 
FROM `pay_administrator_actions` 
INNER JOIN `pay_administrator` 
ON pay_administrator.admin_uid = pay_administrator_actions.admin_uid 
WHERE (CONCAT(pay_administrator.admin_vfname, pay_administrator.admin_vlname) LIKE '%Daly%') 
LIMIT 10 

public function findActionsByName($name, $page, $rowCount) 
{
    $name = '%'.$name.'%';                
    $select = $this->select();
    $select->setIntegrityCheck(false);                
    $select->from('pay_administrator_actions');  
    $select->join('pay_administrator', 'pay_administrator.admin_uid = pay_administrator_actions.admin_uid', 'pay_administrator_actions.*');
    $select->where('CONCAT(pay_administrator.admin_vfname, pay_administrator.admin_vlname) LIKE  ?', $name);
    $select->limitPage($page, $rowCount);                
    return $this->fetchAll($select);
}
```

Comment: admin_vfname is in pay_administrator and in the query it is selecting * from that table so not sure why it can't find the row?

Comment: Change `pay_administrator_actions.*` to `pay_administrator.*` in your join.

Comment: Oh I see it now, woops, thank you put that as an answer and I'll accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as per my comment you need to change `pay_administrator_actions.*` to `pay_administrator.*` in your join.

```
$select->join('pay_administrator', 'pay_administrator.admin_uid =    
pay_administrator_actions.admin_uid', 'pay_administrator.*');
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this error, turned out I had a space after column alias. So something like:

`->from('orders', ('id, count(*) AS total order ')`

Hope this helps another user!